# Restart audio when I do another mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mouseover, restart

here is my Code:

```
<audio id="sound1" src="sound/EinE.mp3"> onmouseover="document.getElementById('sound1').play()"
```

Working fine. But when I leave the mouseover and return with the mouse, the sound do not replay. I have to wait, till the sound play to end. It should start by 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `var a = document.getElementById('sound1'); a.pause(); a.currentTime = 0; a.play()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
<audio id="sound1" src="sound/EinE.mp3" onmouseover="var a = document.getElementById('sound1'); a.pause(); a.currentTime = 0; a.play()">
```

By just doing `a.play()`, you don't restart it. To restart, you should reset the `currentTime` attribute.